Could the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{\{a_n\} \in A_n} G(F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n))$ be noncomputable for some $\{x_n\}$?
My question is the first part of my research work and it is a bit long. Here I am stuck and I need help from MSE .
Let $A_n$ be the set of infinite binary sequences, i.e., sequences where each term is either $0$ or $1$, and the sequence has infinitely many terms. Each sequence in $A_n$ is a function $a_n: \mathbb{N} \to {0, 1}$, where $a_n = (a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots)$ represents a binary sequence.
For each natural number $n$, the set $A_n$ contains exactly $2^n$ distinct sequences such that the first $n$ terms of each sequence are distinct from the first $n$ terms of any other sequence in $A_n$. In other words, $A_n$ is the collection of all infinite sequences whose first $n$ terms are unique. While the set $A_n$ has finitely many sequences for any fixed $n$, the sequences themselves are infinite, meaning they extend beyond the first $n$ terms.
For example, when $n = 3$, the set $A_3$ includes sequences such as $000..., 001..., 010..., \dots, 111...$, where only the first $3$ terms are considered for uniqueness. These sequences are infinite and we are interested in the behavior of these sequences for arbitrary $n$. The infinite sequences in $A_n$ can be either computable or non-computable. Note that, there exist infinitely many different sequences which starts with $000...$, but we can include only one to the set $A_3$ .
Let the function $F: {0, 1}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined as:
$F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) = \frac{x_1a_1 + x_2a_2 + \cdots + x_na_n}{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}$
where $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in {0, 1}$ are the first $n$ terms of a binary sequence and $x_n$ is a some unique positive computable sequence, for instance take $x_n=\sqrt n$.
Next, define the function $G: \mathbb{R} \to {0, 1}$ as follows:
$$G(F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)) =
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if } F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \geq \frac{1}{2}, \\
0, & \text{if } F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) < \frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}$$
Now, consider the following limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum_{\{a_n\} \in A_n} G(F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n))$$
where $A_n$ is the set of infinite binary sequences, each with distinct first $n$ terms.

My research question: Can we define an exact sequence $\{x_n\}$ that makes the above limit non-computable ?

Intuitively, I think that this limit is not always computable for any computable $\{x_n\}$ .
The reasoning is as follows:
As $n \to \infty$, the set $A_n$ can include every unique infinite binary sequence, and these sequences can be either computable or non-computable.
While the function $G$ is computable for all computable sequences, it becomes undecidable (and hence non-computable) for non-computable sequences because the function $F$ itself is not computable for these sequences.
Consequently, the inclusion of non-computable sequences in $A_n$ can introduce undecidability, making the limit non-computable.
However, for any fixed $N$, the ratio
$$\frac{1}{2^N} \sum_{\{a_N\} \in A_N} G(F(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_N))
$$
is always computable because $A_N$ is finite for fixed $N$.
Does there exist such a computable sequence $\{x_n\}$ ? How can we investigate the existence of such $\{x_n\}$ ? Thank you for any help !

Look up Specker sequences https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specker_sequence

@H.CManu Thank you ! Now my question may become more interesting if we choose $x_n$ as a Specker sequence.
